# Can a battery electric vehicle be driven through a dust storm?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, automotive, short-circuit, static-electricity

I would like to know if a battery electric vehicle such as a Tesla Model 3 automobile can be driven through a dust storm.

Back during the Dust Bowl days of the 1930s, driving through a dust storm could damage electrical equipment inside a car.

*"...So much static electricity built up between the ground and airborne dust that blue flames leapt from barbed wire fences and well-wishers shaking hands could generate a spark so powerful it could knock them to the ground. Since static electricity could short out engines and car radios, motorists driving through dust storms dragged chains from the back of their automobiles to ground their cars..."* https://www.history.com/news/10-things-you-may-not-know-about-the-dust-bowl

Can a battery electric vehicle be driven through a dust storm?

Comment: I'm wondering what sensitive and fragile electrical equipment might have been used in a car made in 1930 or earlier.

Comment: Chain dragging is probably true.   Cars crapping out doesn't seem right.  Even today I see trucks with intentional chains dragging.   Could be to prevent the driver getting a super zap when getting out of the car rather than the cars electrical system being at risk.

Comment: This question will result in an opinion/experience based discussions. I would think that the best guidance can be provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: @Syed, that is a good suggestion. I think I will contact companies such as Tesla, GM, and Ford and ask them if the static electricity generated by a dust storm would have any effect on the battery or other electronics inside their vehicles.

Comment: I don't see exactly how my question is off-topic. It is a historical fact that dust storms have generated high levels of static electricity inside automobiles and this static electricity did damage to electrical equipment inside automobiles

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, because the dust will get into the cooling system

Electric cars have cooling systems, typically with liquid cooling.  Also, the heat pump system for cabin air has a large Freon radiator of its own. (some only air condition the cabin, others run the heat pump in both directions and make heat too.) To the extent any motors are air-cooled (e.g. cabin fan motor, radiator fan motor, windshield wiper motors) they will also collect dust.

The core electronics and drive motor are probably reasonably sealed to keep rain out; liquid cooling really removes the reason for them to have ventilation.

Comment: that's an interesting point you make about dust affecting the cooling system, I had not considered that. I am more concerned though about a high level of static electricity quickly damaging the battery and electronics inside an electric vehicle.

Comment: @user57467 it would probably do the same thing lightning does to a jetliner.